# How to implement an autopilot

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am working on building a texted based space game with .net  I have a server and client where I am able to "move" around the map.  The map is broken down by sectors, which each sector having a possibility of connecting to up to 8 other sectors around it (a grid with diagonal movement as well). This is stored in the sector class by an array listing the connecting sectors. Currently, all the sectors are stored in a List.  When a move command is issued, the connecting sector array is checked and if the requested sector is found in the array, the new sector is loaded.

What I would like to do is implement an autopilot function, but for the life of me cannot figure out how to pull it off with my current structures.  Each sector only knows about it's connecting sectors.

Does anyone have any suggestions / ideas?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a shortest path algorithm. The sectors form a graph and you want to find a route through the sectors.

Simplest way to do this is to do two concurrent breadth first searches starting from the ship's current position and the place you want to get. When you find a shared node, merge the paths to that node from each location and you have a path.

You can optimize this with A* if you have any proximity data.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways of doing this. Is your map like space itself, where you can travel in all directions, or is it more like a maze? As a space game, I'd have imagined the map to be

```
XXXX
XXXX
XXXX
XXXX
```

In such a case, you might be better off using a 2d array to store the map. This will allow you to just autopilot by increasing X and Y until you find your destination.

However, if your map is more complex, you should investigate the "A* algorithm" for navigation. What you do is brute force your way to the best path, by calculating every possible route, and picking the shortest. For example, if your map is:

```
 X
XXX
A B
```

And you're trying to get from A to B, you generate a map:

(U=up, etc.)

```
U
UR
URU
URUD
URUDR
URUDRD*
URR
URRD*
```

It will look something like that. The * means that route found its way to the destination, so then it looks at all the ones that made it, and picks the shortest.

An advantage of A* is you can apply weighting for each sector. If you have a nebula in one sector that takes 3 times as long to pass through, you can include this in your algorithm by comparing the total 'effort' instead of the number of operations. This is cool in games where your character navigates via the path because the path is much faster :)

There are many algorithms for this online, just search for A* pathfinding. Good luck!